# How to measure the impact of data-movement in my Spark Job?

Tags: apache-spark

Some concepts of how to use Apache Spark efficiently with a database are not yet clear to me.

I was reading the book *Spark: Big Data made simple* and the author states (ch.1 pg.5):

> "*Data is expensive to move so Spark focuses on performing computations over the data, no matter where it resides*."

and

> "*Although Spark runs well on Hadoop storage, today it is also used broadly in environments for which the Hadoop architecture does not make sense, such as the public cloud (where storage can be purchased separately from computing) or streaming applications.*"

I understood that, at its philosophy, Spark decouples storage from computing. In practice, this can lead to data movement when the data does not reside in the same physical machine as the spark Workers.

My questions are:

1. How to measure the impact of data movement in my Job? For example, how to know if the network/database throughput is the bottleneck in my Spark job?
2. What's the IDEAL (if exists) use of spark? Tightly coupled processing + data storage, with the workers in the same physical machine as the database instances, for minimal data movement? Or can I use a single database instance (with various workers) as long as it can handle a high throughput and network traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a super-fast network connection, data is no longer costly to move. It was the case 15 years ago but not anymore. Most spark jobs are running nowadays with the data residing in an object store like s3. When spark runs, it fetches the data from s3 and performs the operation. We like this approach because this allows us not to maintain a massive Hadoop long-running cluster. We run the spark job when required.

The minimal data movement hypothesis is no longer valid. The major bottleneck in modern computing is CPU speed, not the data transfer cost.

However, to your question, about how to measure the data transfer cost: You can run two experiments one with data in Hadoop cluster and one with data in an object stores like s3 and check what's the time difference in the spark job.

Important thing to note, it is not always important to run spark job super fast. You need to keep a balance between your workflow SLA requirement and maintainability of the cluster and data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with data in s3 IO load at 5K/s read, 3K/s write and inefficiencies of GET requests dominate bandwidth. If you are doing too much S3 IO against the same part of an S3 bucket, you get throttled -and adding more workers just makes it worse.

Also S3 latency isn't great when the input stream needs to drain/abort the current request and start a new GET with a different range.

if you are using the s3a connector and you are using a recent 3.3.3+ hadoop jars (and you should) then you can get it to print lots of stats on S3 IO.

- if you call toString() on an input stream it prints the IO it has done: bytes read, discarded, GET calls, latency.
- if you set `spark.hadoop.fs.iostatistics.logging.level` to "info" you get a summary of all IO done against a bucket when a worker process is shut down.